# Add an Object to an NSDictionarry in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have the following Objective-C code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *options = // some values

options[kCRToastInteractionRespondersKey] = 
   @[[CRToastInteractionResponder interactionResponderWithInteractionType:CRToastInteractionTypeTap                                                                                                          
              automaticallyDismiss:YES                                                                                                                              
              block:^(CRToastInteractionType interactionType){                                                                                                                              
                  NSLog(@"Dismissed with %@ interaction", 
                  NSStringFromCRToastInteractionType(interactionType));                                                                                                                          
              }]];
```

I want to create the equivalent in Swift:

```
var options:[NSObject:AnyObject] = [:]
options[kCRToastInteractionRespondersKey] = CRToastInteractionResponder(interactionType: CRToastInteractionType.Tap, automaticallyDismiss: true) { (r:CRToastInteractionType) -> Void in }
```

When I run the code I get the error:

```
ERROR given <CRToastInteractionResponder: 0x7b9e2cd0> for key kCRToastInteractionRespondersKey was expecting Class NSArray but got Class CRToastInteractionResponder, passing default on instead
```

**How do I add the `CRToastInteractionResponder` correctly to the NSDictionary in Swift?**

**Edit:**

I also tried

```
var options:NSDictionary = [:]
```

but then I have to cast options to `[NSObject : AnyObject]` when calling it with:

```
CRToastManager.showNotificationWithOptions(options as [NSObject : AnyObject], completionBlock: { () -> Void in
  println("done!")
})
```

The error remains still the same.

Comment: Try changing to var options:NSDictionary instead.

Comment: @iosDev82 Still not working. Got the same error see my post.

Comment: Notice that you are trying to do very different things in your Objective-C and Swift code. The Objective-C code sets the value to an array containing one element which is an interaction responder. The Swift code tries to set the value to an interaction responder itself. So the first thing is to make up your mind what you want to do.

Comment: @matt I want to translate the Objective-C statement in the first lines to the Swift equivalent?

Comment: And I'm pointing out that you are not doing so.

Comment: I'm not going to translate your code for you. Think about what I'm saying. You are getting a runtime error, not a compile error. So what you are doing is valid Swift. But it is not what CRToast wants. The problem is that you didn't make an array. Think about it and fix it.

Comment: @matt I posted the solution. Can you confirm that it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the solution:

```
var options:[NSObject:AnyObject] = [:]
options[kCRToastInteractionRespondersKey] = [CRToastInteractionResponder(interactionType: CRToastInteractionType.Tap, automaticallyDismiss: true) { (r:CRToastInteractionType) -> Void in }]
```

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary can have objects at the time of initialisation so you can not add object after it's initialisation.

So you need NSMutableDictionary.

You can write

```
var options:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
options .setObject("your object to store", forKey: kCRToastInteractionRespondersKey)
```

or you can store result of the block in **var** and the later add to dictionary.

Hope this will help you.